# How to run a for loop for 0 to an output from a query in SAP HANA Sp12

Tags: hana

I have to run a for loop from 0 to a number(which i get from doing count(*) on a table).

Here is my code along with the error I'm getting :

**Error :**

Could not execute 'ALTER PROCEDURE HADMIN.PROC_PH_CSR_CURR_STOCK() LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT SQL SECURITY INVOKER DEFAULT ...' SAP DBTech JDBC: [1310]: scalar type is not allowed: V_CNT: line 138 col 1 (at pos 4829)

**Code:**

```
v_cnt = select count(*) from :t_rst;

truncate table HADMIN.PH_SUM_CSR_CURR_STOCK;

FOR X IN 0 .. v_cnt DO
IF :X <= v_cnt THEN
            CONTINUE;
        ELSEIF :X > v_cnt THEN
            BREAK;
        ELSE
            count := count + 2500000;         
        END IF;
    END FOR;

INSERT INTO HADMIN.PH_SUM_CSR_CURR_STOCK
SELECT * FROM :t_rst LIMIT 2500000 OFFSET :count;
COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing variable values in SAP HANA SQLScript you need to use the colon `:` prefix.
Also, to assign a single from your `count(*)` to a variable you need to use `SELECT ... INTO`.
A `var_name = SELECT ...` declares and assigns a *table variable* that can contain tuples, not scalars (which is what you want in this case).

```
select count(*) into v_cnt from :t_rst;

truncate table HADMIN.PH_SUM_CSR_CURR_STOCK;

FOR X IN 0 .. :v_cnt DO
IF :X <= :v_cnt THEN
            CONTINUE;
        ELSEIF :X > :v_cnt THEN
            BREAK;
        ELSE
            count := :count + 2500000;         
        END IF;
    END FOR;

INSERT INTO HADMIN.PH_SUM_CSR_CURR_STOCK
    SELECT * FROM :t_rst LIMIT 2500000 OFFSET :count;
COMMIT;
END;
```